# Python : Collection insert error in Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a collection to Mongo DB cluster but I am facing a server selection timeout error. I am able to connect to Mongo DB successfully but get timeout error on inserting a collection. How do I resolve the same ?

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-02.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-00.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-01.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64366abcce869e3342d6b6a5, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-00.masfo3b.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-00.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-01.masfo3b.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-01.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-02.masfo3b.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ho1c2e3-shard-00-02.masfo3b.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')>]>

Following code that is being used

```
import pymongo
import pandas
database_name = "mydb"  

try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.masfo3b.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",connectTimeoutMS=30000,socketTimeoutMS=None)
    db = client[database_name]
    print("MongoDB Connection successful")
except:  
    print("Failed MongoDB connection")

Coll = 'SPL'
splColl =  db[Coll]

spAddressData2 = pd.read_excel('Addresses.xlsx')
records2 = json.loads(spAddressData2.T.to_json()).values()
splAddressColl.insert_many(records2)
splAddressColl.create_index([('Address', 'text')])
```

Comment: Is this using an Atlas cluster?

Comment: yes, used an Atlas cluster

Comment: Have you whitelisted your IP address? Try connecting with the mongo shell, if it fails in the same way it's probably the case that your IP address isn't whitelisted. Be aware that you may have a dynamic IP address which can complicate this issue.